# how to fetch array with map from other js file in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to fetch array from the product file but it is showing
`'Uncaught TypeError: _product__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...).map is not a function'`
I have even tried using key in Col but still it is showing the same.
My react code is

```
import product from '../product'

export default function HomeScreen() {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Latest Products</h1>
            <Row>
                {product.map((products)=>(
                    <Col sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                        <h3>{products.name}</h3>
                    </Col>
                ))}
            </Row>
        </>
    )
}
```

and product file is

```
const product=[
    {
        _id:'1',
        name : 'Shoes',
        images : './img.shoe4.jfif',
        discription : 'Lorem10j,jdscjscjc nxkd kdn ddksad asdkjdhsadb',
        brand : 'Apple',
        category : 'Electronics',
        price : 89.3,
        countInStocks : 3,
        rating: 4.5,
        numReviews: 4
    }  

];
```

Comment: it seems you haven't exported product list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the actual problem is that the `product` in your `HomeScreen` is not an array,
seems like you are not exporting your `product` array from its file,

it should be like this :

```
//don't forget the export keyword if you want to access it outside this file
const product=[
    {
        _id:'1',
        name : 'Shoes',
        images : './img.shoe4.jfif',
        discription : 'Lorem10j,jdscjscjc nxkd kdn ddksad asdkjdhsadb',
        brand : 'Apple',
        category : 'Electronics',
        price : 89.3,
        countInStocks : 3,
        rating: 4.5,
        numReviews: 4
    }  
];
export default product;
```

Comment: this is not working with default import, either export a const and use a named import or export default to keep the mentioned import.

Answer (score 0):

You have to export products from your products file.

Either use default export:

```
export default product;
```

and use the following import:

```
import product from '../product';
```

or use a named import:

```
export const product = [{ ... }]
```

and import the named const:

```
import { product } from '../product'
```